# what to use as reference for proofs and laws

Tags: reference-request

I am new to Math. I come from a CS background, where its easy to find reference material for anything, eg the C++ reference specification if one wants to know peculiarities of C++.

Whats the equivalent for Math? For example, where does one go to find the precis reference for Logarithm power laws?

Comment: https://www.pearson.com/en-us/subject-catalog/p/college-algebra-and-trigonometry/P200000008688/9780134314419